# Apache Configuration Tuning

Tags: apache, config

I need to tune my apache2 Config to handle 1500 Connections simultaneously. Each request user makes it never ends and he gets data all the time except if he press the stop from his browser.

My Current Config Is:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers 15
        MinSpareServers 5
        MaxSpareServers 50
        ServerLimit 5000
        MaxClients 5000
        MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          40
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Which i have no idea if this is tuned. Also do i need to tune something else other tan prefork_module and worker module?

Please note that the server is really strong with 12 Cores and 64GB Ram.

Thank you

Comment: Well which worker are you using, worker or prefork?

Comment: i have no idea what to use. And in the apache2.conf it has both exactly like i gave it to you.